# Add message if no content is found for appended class

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery to append a calendar event to display elsewhere on my site , but when there is no event to display , i'd like to put a message in the new .event class saying "No current events"

```
    $('#monthly_calendar td.today ul').appendTo('#todayscalendar .event');

    <table id="todayscalendar">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="event">
</tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

I tried adding this below the existing function but it didn't work

```
$("#todayscalendar .event:empty").text("No current events");
```

Comment: You're appending a `<ul>` to a `<tr>`?  Or am I mis-reading that first line?  I'm just wondering if maybe your code isn't working because your HTML is invalid.

Comment: If you are appending a tag into `.event` then it is not empty, so that code will never work since event is never empty

Comment: It's probably not empty anymore after you appended a `ul` to the `tr`.. Also, `tr` should have a `td` in it.

Comment: i checked the source , and when it's empty no ul class is added to the tr , so the tr is empty and should work

Comment: found my issue , i had a space between closing my </tr> once i opened and closed with no space , it worked

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the `.html()` function?, it changes the inner html of the element

```
$("#todayscalendar .event:empty").html("<td>No current events</td>");
```

also: add the `<td>` tags

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Cheloideman/yq2a4kts/)

[JQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: this worked fine as well , the issue i had was the spacing with closing my </tr> , which seems odd , but if you add any spacing it won't work